# react awesome query builder limitations with mongodb and embedded doc collections

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, builder

I have 2 collections, Authors and Books and I want to use react-awesome-query-builder to enable the user to query the data however they like, here are my schemas and data

Authors collection

```
{id: 1, name: 'JK Rowling', gender: 'F'},
{id: 2, name: 'Roald Dahl', gender: 'M'},
{id: 3, name: 'Dr Seuss',   gender: 'M'}
```

Books collection

```
{id: 1, author_id: 1, title: 'Harry Potter and the Philosophers Stone', year: 1997},
{id: 2, author_id: 1, title: 'Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire',     year: 2000},
{id: 3, author_id: 2, title: 'Charlie and the Chocolate Factory',       year: 1964},
{id: 4, author_id: 2, title: 'James and the giant peach',               year: 1961},
{id: 5, author_id: 3, title: 'Green eggs and ham',                      year: 1960},
{id: 6, author_id: 3, title: 'The cat in the hat',                      year: 1957}
```

I want to be able to build query to 'show me all authors that released books in the 1960s', and it return me the mongo query allows me to query, which when executed returns the following results:

```
{id: 2, name: 'Roald Dahl'},
{id: 3, name: 'Dr Seuss'}
```

I am not sure how to arrange my data, one collection of 'authors' with embedded array of 'books' documents, or two separate collections or a combination of the two?

Mongo works well with embedded documents but not sure of the capability of react-awesome-query-builder?

Answer (score 2):

It appears that $elemmatch support has been added to react-awesome-query-builder so I just needed to change my !struct config to !group and voila!